# how to get rid of the orders of zeroes of analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading complex variable theory by fisher.In ch 3 i faced the following problem.
let me draw the background.

Then i will ask the problem,show my attempt.

Suppose that h is an analytic function  on a domain $\mathcal{D}$ except for a finite number of poles.
Let $\gamma$ be a piecewise smooth close curvein $\mathcal{D}$
 whose inside lies in $\mathcal{D}$.
  and which passes through no zeroes or poles of h.
  Let $z_1,z_2,\cdot \cdot z_n$ be the distinct zeroes of h inside $\gamma$ and let $w_1,w_2,\cdot \cdot w_n$ be distinct poles of h inside $\gamma$

Let $n_j$ be the order of zero of h at $z_j,j=1,2,\cdot \cdot N$

Then 
$$
h(z)=(z-z_j)^{n_j}G_j(z)
$$
where $G_j$ is analytic near $z_j$ and $G_j(z_j)\neq 0$.
Hence
$$
\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}=\frac{n_j}{(z-z_j)}+\frac{G'_j(z)}{G_j(z)}
$$
so we get
$$
Res\Big(
\frac{h'}{h};z_j
\Big)=n_j
$$

Likewise if $m_k$ is the order of the pole of h at $w_k,k=1,2...M$ then

$$
h(z)=\frac{H(z)}{(z-w_k)^{m_k}}
$$
where $H_k$ is analytic near $w_k$ and $H_k(w_k)\neq 0$
Thus
$$
\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}=\frac{-m_k}{z-w_k}+\frac{H'_k}{H_k}
$$
for z near $w_k$ so
$$
Res\Big(
\frac{h'}{h};w_k
\Big)=-m_k
$$

Applying the residue thm to the function $\frac{h'}{h}$ we get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}dz=
\sum_{j=1}^N n_j-\sum_{k=1}^M m_k
$$

ok,thats the background.Now in the exercise the  statement is

Suppose g be an analytic function on a domain containing $\gamma$ and its inside.
 then
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}g(z)dz=
\sum_{j=1}^N  g(z_i)-\sum_{k=1}^M g(w_j)
$$

where $z_1,....z_n$ are the zeroes and $w_1,....w_n$ are the poles of h inside $\gamma$,each listed according to its $\textit{multiplicity}$

An obvious thing to do is multiply $g(z)$ with $\frac{h'}{h}$ and the residue then becomes
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow z_j}
\frac{h'}{h}g(z)=n_jg(z_j)
$$
but cant get rid of the $n_j$

Again $g(z)$ is analytic inside the domain $\mathcal{D}$.so integrating along $\gamma$ will yield 0 due to no pole.and also $g'(z)$ is analytic inside $\mathcal{D}$.so integrating it too along $\gamma$ yield 0
and $(gh)'=g'h+h'g$ so $h'g=(gh)'-g'h$ dividing by $h$ we get
$$
\frac{h'}{h}g=\frac{(gh)'}{h}+\frac{g'h}{h}
$$
 the seond term is $g'$ which will give zero  integrating along $\gamma$

now writing $h(z)$ near a pole $z_j$, $h(z)=(z-z_j)^nG(z)$ ,where $G(z)$
is regular analytic inside $\mathcal{D}$ we see

$$
\begin{split}
(hg)'=&((z-z_j)^nG(z)g)'\\
=& n(z-z_j)^{n-1}Gg+(z-z_j)^nG'(z)g+(z-z_j)^nG(z)g'
\end{split}
$$

dividing by $h$ we get

$$
\frac{(hg)'}{h}=\frac{ng}{(z-z_j)}+\frac{G'g}{G}+g'
$$

but then again the residue is still $n_jg(z_j)$ as $\lim{z\rightarrow z_j}$

Comment: Search argument principle on wikipedia. The formula after ‘suppose $g$ be an analytic function...’ is wrong.